# Google Prediction API : Error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, google-prediction, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run the [Prediction API example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/prediction-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/prediction/cmdline/PredictionSample.java?repo=samples). Everything is configured by following [these instructions](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/prediction-cmdline-sample/instructions.html), but the only message I received is:

```
500 Internal Server Error
{
   "code" : 500,
   "message" : null
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could not find what I'm missing...
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using an older version of the Prediction API - v1.5.  The current version is v1.6, you can find some sample code here - https://github.com/gxlzlihao/GooglePredictionAPISample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/prediction/cmdline/PredictionSample.java